# Using group by and self join to find duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that i am attempting to query which looks like this:

```
t_documents
id
user_id
submitted_date
text
status
```

A user can have multiple documents in the documents table and is free to submit the same text multiple times. I wanted a way to see how many duplicate submissions are made per user. So for ex:

```
VALUES (1, 1234, 2016-07-05, "this is a test", 3)
VALUES (2, 1234, 2016-07-06, "this is a test", 3)
VALUES (3, 5678, 2016-07-07, "this is another test", 3)
VALUES (4, 5678, 2016-07-08, "this is another test", 3)
```

For the above set of data, I wanted a result that says give me a record for user 1234, the duplicate text and the number of times the duplicate text has been submitted. I have tried the following:

```
select oring.user_id, orig.text, COUNT(1) as dups
from t_documents orig
join t_documents another
on orig.user_id = another.user_id
and orig.text = another.text
group by user_id
```

The above is super rough and does not work. Can anyone please advise how to do what I want? Another query I would be interested in would be, in total, how many duplicate entries are there across all the users?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `text` is a keyword. You should not use that for a column name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that you need a self-join here.  A simple `GROUP BY` on the user ID and text columns should suffice:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS dup_count
FROM t_documents
GROUP BY user_id, text
```

I assume here that you *don't* care about the posting date when determining whether a text be duplicate or not.

**Edit:**

If you want to find the total number of duplicates among all users then you can try the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(t.dup_count)
FROM
(
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT text) AS dup_count
    FROM t_documents
    GROUP BY user_id
) t
```

Comment: i get an error that text must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: But `text` _does_ appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Are you sure you are running my query and not something else?

Comment: what about my other query? to get number of all duplicate entries across all users? so like, not finding dups per user, rather dups in the documents table itself?

Comment: what if (unlikey but still possible), two user's had the same text. the last query would mistakenly pick those two documents as duplicates

Comment: @JohnBaum I rephrased the query to deal with this scenario.

Comment: Still new to sql, is it fair to assume that anything comma separated in group by will be used to compare duplicates above? Like if i did GROUP BY user_id, text, status in the first query for example, it would find all the entries for the user that have the same user_id, text and status?

Comment: If you're referring to my first query, specifically the count in that query, then yes, it would return the number of entries for the same `user_id`, `text`, and `status`.  Feel free to open a new question if you want.

Comment: Sorry, last one i hope. In the second query, what if i want to count all the duplicates for all users where text AND status are the same (ie cant get away with the distinct on just the text)

Comment: You should ask a new question.  This query would be very different from what you initially asked.